# What is wrong with this Rails routing constraint?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, constraints

I am trying to write a routing constraint which roots dependant upon presence of a devise User's nested resource.

```
User has_one Company, Company belongs_to User.
Company has_many Quotes, Quote belongs_to Company.
```

I would like to root as follows;

```
root 'quotes#new', contraints: CompanyPresentConstraint.new
root 'companies#new'
```

I have in app/contraints/company_present_constraint.rb;

```
class CompanyPresentConstraint
    def current_user(request)
      User.find_by_id(request.session[:user_id])
    end

    def matches?(request)
        user = current_user(request)
        user.company.present?
    end
end
```

A User, that has a company, GETing '/' is routed to Quotes#new just fine, but a User without a company is still routed to Quotes#new, and it's failing because the @company object is not available for the nested form_for, despite routes.rb specifying that no company presence should route to companies#new,  as above.

The reason that i know that the constraint seems to be failing is that my Quotes#new view has; `%= simple_form_for [@company,@quote] do |quote| %>` and when logging in as a user which i know does not have a company the error given is `undefined method 'quotes_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fb455cf9c78>:0x007fb453c2c478>` which shows that despite this user not having a company, they're still being routed to Quotes#new.

I am unsure where the issue is here, can anyone point it out?

Thanks

Points of pertinence;

- under all circumstances root routes to quotes#new, therefore `#matches?` must not be operating as intended?
- All controllers and routes must be devise user_authenticated.
- What happens when a user without a company is routed to quotes#new is that the nested form for which requires @company and @quote object fails, as above.

Ideas:

- Is the constraint in the right place and automatically loaded?
- Is `#matches?` doing what I intend? i.e. checking presence of company on a user located via `session[:user_id]`? Good point brought up in comments that the constraint is 'pre routing' thus the routed controller#action has not enfored the devise user_authentication, thus session may not be available. However, despite this being the case, routes.rb still sends root to `quotes#new` not `comapnies#new` as it should do if it was unable to return true from `#matches?`.

Comment: I don't think you have access to the current user at that point of the request cycle. One way you could do it was to simply decide on the root controller action (where you'll have access to the full request and session) if to show the new quote or redirect to a new route like `/company`. Basically, have 1 root, but redirect to another path if no company (and I imagine if no user redirect somewhere else).

Comment: Thanks @micael-nussbaumer, though both the `Companies` and the `Quotes` controllers have to `authenticate_user!` for all of these actions, so user is already logged in, therefore I should have access to `session[:user_id]`, no?

Comment: No. You're deciding pre-routing right? If you're saying "route to this if that", how could `this` authenticate if it hasn't been hit yet and you're still deciding?

Comment: I'm deciding which controller and action root should call, though because every controller and action is user authenticable, none of the views can be accessed until the user has signed in, therefore the root to `quotes#new` or `companies#new` will only ever be hit with a signed in user, thus session will therefore be available? Apologies if I'm not understanding something pretty fundamental here.

Comment: Even if `CompanyPresentConstraint.new.matches?` fails, i.e. User has not created a Company yet, the app is still routing to `Quotes#new`

Comment: I understand your point now @micael-nussbaumer, apologies! So that's right that the session object wouldn't be available because they've not been prompted to sign in, because the controller action has not been hit, but if this is the case then `#matches?` on the Constraint should fail and route to companies#new, and this is not the case, it is always routing to Quotes#new!?

Comment: first you have a typo on `constraint`, on the route, and on the folder path, once you correct that you should see if it's autoloaded or not because if not it will raise an error, and lastly if you want to route an user based on the attributes of that user shouldn't you do that after the point where you identify the user and not before? I've tried accessing session[] and it was not defined (as expected). The request object does have a session element to it, but it's not accessible.

Comment: Thank you, typo has moved error on to `undefined method 'company' for nil:NilClass` as correct there's no user. Ok, so clearly my approach here is wrong, perhaps driven by poor design. What I am trying to do is get users as quickly as possible to the `Quotes#new` view and once a user has logged in, take them there if they already have a company created and if not take them to Companies#new. Any recommendations as to how I can change the design here, whilst reducing the length of the hourbey to get a user to Quotes#new?

Comment: You can just conditionally render a partial or other? On controller check if `user.company.present?` if yes you set `@quote = Quote.new` if not `@company = Company.new`, then on your view `<%= @quote ? (render 'quote_partial') : (render 'company_partial')  %>`

Comment: That sounds like a much better solution. However both partials are under different controllers, Company#new renders all the company form partials and the same for Quote#new. Are you suggesting move everything into a single controller? Wonder what a usual pattern would be for such a situation, can't be a particularly novel use case surely.

Comment: I wonder too, let me know when you find out

Comment: Hs, will do Michel, thanks.